# How to define constants in headers to use in multiple C files

Tags: c, constants, header-files

When writing C code, I might want to define a constant array in a header file so that it may be used in multiple `.c` files.

Take the following example:

**main.c**

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

int main() {
  int localmat[9];
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    localmat[i] = HEADERMAT[i];
  }
  matadd(localmat, HEADERMAT);
  return 0;
}
```

**main.h**

```c
#ifndef _MAIN_H_
#define _MAIN_H_

// Constant array
const int HEADERMAT[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

// prototype function:
void matadd(int matA[9], const int matB[9]);

#endif
```

**functions.c**

```c
#include "main.h"

void matadd(int matA[9], const int matB[9]){
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    matA[i] += matB[i];
  }
}
```

The constant array `HEADERMAT` declared in `main.h` is used in both
`main.c` and `functions.h`. The header does use ifndef to prevent redefinitions and yet, the compiler will still complain about it being defined multiple times:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccVWhI0u.o:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `HEADERMAT'; /tmp/ccRAIQ5u.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What would be the better way of making this array accessible to both C files?

Comment: See ["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1674032/15168) for a discussion of simple scalar values as constants.  An array is a different animal.  You'll need to select a source file to define the array, and declare (but not define) it in the header.  Or you have to define it as `static` in the header, but then you run into problems with repetition of the data (which may not matter for a 36-byte array but would definitely be a problem for an array of many kilobytes).  You might be able to finagle the problems with an `inline` function, but it's tricky at best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you simply want to make the `HEADERMAT[]` array available in multiple source files, you can simply declare it as usual in any of the source files and then declare it as `extern` in any other source file that needs it.

To do so, you need to

1. define a macro for the array size in a common header so all sources will know the size of the array, e.g. `#define HEADERMATSZ 9`,
2. declare the array as usual in one of the C source files, e.g. `const int HEADERMAT[HEADERMATSZ] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};`,
3. in any other C source files that need access, declare `extern const int HEADERMAT[HEADERMATSZ];`.

Now you can simply use `HEADERMAT[]` as needed in any file where it is either declared originally, or as `extern`.

A short example, first the common header to be included by `main.c` and `source1.c` that holds a function that will use the array declared as `extern`, e.g.

```c
#ifndef COMMONHDR
#define COMMONHDR  1

#define HEADERMATSZ 9     /* defined size of extern array */

void showoutput (void);   /* declaration of function using extern array*/


#endif
```

For your `main.c` we will declare the array there, including the common header to provide the *declaration* for the function we will call from `source1.c` that uses the array declared `extern`, e.g.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "commonhdr.h"

const int HEADERMAT[HEADERMATSZ] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};


int main (void) {
  
  puts ("output from other file");
  showoutput();
}
```

(the `showoutput()` function being the function called from `source1.c`, also note `HEADERMATSZ` can be omitted if your initializer has the correct number of values -- including it ensures the array is sized correctly)

Finally the `source1.c` file we provide the function *definition* that uses the array `extern`,

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "commonhdr.h"

extern const int HEADERMAT[HEADERMATSZ];

/* definition of function using extern array */
void showoutput (void)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < HEADERMATSZ; i++) {
    printf (" %d  %d\n", i, HEADERMAT[i]);
  }
}
```

Compile both sources into the final executable, e.g. with gcc,

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wshadow -std=c11 -Ofast source1.c -o main main.c
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./main
output from other file
 0  0
 1  1
 2  2
 3  3
 4  4
 5  5
 6  6
 7  7
 8  8
```

This method works well regardless whether it is on your PC or programming a micro-controller. By using extern, the array need not be `const` and can be modified in either source if it is mutable.

Answer (score 0):

Header files are for declarations. So, this is one way:

```c
// main.h
#ifndef _MAIN_H_
#define _MAIN_H_

// Constant array
const int HEADERMAT[9]; // <---- declaration only
 
// prototype function:
void matadd(int matA[9], const int matB[9]);

#endif
```

Then, in *some* source file (preferably `main.c`, since we declared in `main.h`)

```c
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "main.h"

const int HEADERMAT[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; // <---- definition here

int main() {
  int localmat[9];
  for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    localmat[i] = HEADERMAT[i];
  }
  matadd(localmat, HEADERMAT);
  return 0;
}
```

If you did it this way in the header file instead:

```c
// main.h
// main.h
#ifndef _MAIN_H_
#define _MAIN_H_

// Constant array
static const int HEADERMAT[9] = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}; // <-- static definition

// prototype function:
void matadd(int matA[9], const int matB[9]);

#endif
```

Then the array would be duplicated in *every* source file that included `main.h`, which, as the Jonathan Leffler's comments point out, is not that big of a deal (36 bytes). But for an array of appreciable size, the waste would be a concern.