# Which is more secure, #define, global variables, or neither?

Tags: arrays, macros, global-variables

I have read on this forum that:

1. macros and #define should be avoided because they are not type safe
2. don't use global variables - some members even describe them as evil

The length of many fixed arrays (probably about 20) is known at compile time and their length will never change so which should I use? Or is it better to type the array length as a straight number every time?

Although I do extensive research before I ask a question for some reason I missed this detailed reply:

["static const" vs "#define" vs "enum"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674032/static-const-vs-define-vs-enum)

I now believe this question should now closed.
After reading Jonathan Leffler's answer I decided to use enum.

Comment: What tool or language is this about? Type safety and problems of global variables are more about clean and bug-free code than about security, although there might be security implications.

Comment: I personally see no big problem in using `#define A_SPECIFIC_ARRAY_SIZE 245` as long as you use this macro only for the intended purpose.

Comment: *"Or is it better to type the array length as a straight number every time"* Depending on the datastructures you use (especially if they don't have built-in method to determine the number of elements they contain), this might be the worst approach, because refactoring such a situation (for instance when you need to change the size of your arrays) is cumbersome and error prone.