# Use of static variables in a header file

Tags: c, static

what is use of having static variables defined in a header file . Each source file include the header file will get its own copy . what is the use of this ?

This questions was asked in one of the interview for me. He stressed me to give the use.He said they are using this in their code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92546/variable-declarations-in-header-files-static-or-not?rq=1

Comment: Maybe the purpose is that each translation unit gets its own copy of the variable.

Comment: Suggest posting the sample code in question.  Talking about it is secondary to the code.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possibly an error, exactly for the reason that you are pointing out. On the other hand, you will sometimes see tiny static functions in a header, where the programmer either didn't care that the code would be duplicated, or hoped that the code would be removed by the linker or inlined.

Since it *is* unusual and suspicious, the programmer should have written a comment why this is being done if they had a good reason. No comment makes it more likely that there was no good reason.

Answer (score 0):

If in header one include rule is obeyed then static - means not for linkage (is analog of anonymous namespace in C++)