# c++ - What is going on with header and .cpp with my static function? runs only when defined in header

Tags: c++, function, static, header

I'm currently learning java at my university and I'm trying to keep up with C++ while we cover new stuff. In java I have static member fields and methods that are independent of objects created. This is what I'm aiming to do in c++.

I have a static function in the Collision.h file.

The program will compile only when I define the static function in the header file.

```
//.h file
static void debug() //compiles and function is usable
    {
        std::cout << "DEBUG from the collision class called in main" << std::endl;
    }

//.cpp file
// <nothing>
```

when I define the function in the .cpp file the program will not compile.

```
//.h file
static void debug(); //does not compile

//.cpp file
    void debug() //I've tried with and without static keyword here.
    {
        std::cout << "DEBUG from the collision class called in main" << std::endl;
    }
```

I'm at a loss as to why this latter situation doesn't work. Are .cpp files only used when an object is created?

Thanks for any help. :)

Comment: the following link might clear your concept

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92546/variable-declarations-in-header-files-static-or-not

Answer (score 3):

A free function is already independent from objects. In C++ `static` has a few different meanings. For free functions, `static` means that the function has internal linkage, meaning it is only visible in the current translation unit (cpp file + headers).

Since your function is declared in a header you don't want the `static` keyword, otherwise every file that includes it will need to implement it (they essentially get there own version of the function). You also shouldn't define it in the header - leave it as `void debug();`. Define it in a cpp file instead.