# Declare value in c++ header

Tags: c++, header, declaration

Well, i'm a newbie to C++ from Python and not familiar with declaring variable in header file. I am trying to create several .cpp file in which calculate some values from some the same constant value set. My code something like:

```
/Global_input.h/
extern int y = 1;
extern int x = 2;

/Properties_1.cpp/
//I wanna calculate z = x + y
include<Global_input.h>
int z;

/Properties_2.cpp/
//I wanna calculate g = x*y
include<Global_input.h>
int g;
```

I got stuck here, the way I search is create a new class or another .cpp file. Can I directly call x,y for such simple cases. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use static const variable for this purpose:

```
static const int x = 1;
```

The `const` keyword here ensures that your code will not change x at any point (you stated that its value is supposed to be constant). I recommend reading the following SO thread to get an idea what the purpose of the `static` keyword is:

[Variable declarations in header files - static or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92546/variable-declarations-in-header-files-static-or-not)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to creating `Global_input.h` also create a `Global_input.cpp` file as follows -

```
/Global_input.h/
extern int y;
extern int x;

/Global_input.cpp/
#include "Global_input.h"

int y = 1;
int x = 2;
```

`extern` just declare the variable not define it. You must define it somewhere else.

Comment: `extern int y = 1;` defines `y` because it has an initializer.

Comment: I guess that is not standard behavior (or at least good practice). Coz both `clang` and `gcc` give warning about it when the header is included in a single translation unit. And if the header is included in multiple translation unit (which is the case here) it complains about multiple references of `x` and `y`.

Comment: That **is** standard behavior. The reason that compilers complain about multiple definitions when you include that header in more than one translation unit is that each translation unit gets a definition.

Answer (score 0):

your my.h files should have this format:

```
//Put before anything else
#ifndef MY_H
#define MY_H

//code goes here

//at the end of your code
#endif
```

your my.cpp files should look like this:

```
//include header file you wish to use
#include "my.h"
```

Comment: or use `#pragma once` and don't worry about things like typos and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the compiler to only read once the header, e.g. like this:

```
/* Global_input.h */
#ifndef GLOBAL_INPUT_H
#define GLOBAL_INPUT_H
    static const int y = 1;
    static const int x = 2;
#endif

/* Properties_1.cpp */
//I wanna calculate z = x + y
#include<Global_input.h>
int z = x + y;

/* Properties_2.cpp */
//I wanna calculate g = x*y
#include<Global_input.h>
int g = x * y;
```